# How to force Ionic to show only menu icon on every page?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How to force Ionic to show only menu icon? 
In Android, I only want to show menu icon for every page. However, in IOS, I want standard navigation (i.e. back button for inner pages).
Is it possible?

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**:

Menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="isAndroid">
    <ion-side-menu-content >
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
            <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="featureContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-content>
           ...
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Home.html

```
<ion-view hide-back-button="isAndroid">
    <ion-content class="home">
        ...
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Please show us some code... I need to see you're html before I can see how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ionic.Platform:

```
$scope.isIOS = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
```

for example:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="homler-nav-bar-with-tabs transparent opposite-direction">
    <ion-nav-back-button ng-show="isIOS" class="button-icon icon-top_button_back light">
    </ion-nav-back-button>
     <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
       <button ng-if="isIOS" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
       <button ng-if="!isIOS" style="display: block" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
     </ion-nav-buttons>
```

Comment: This method does show menu icon on all pages, but I need back-button too. I updated question since it is too ambiguous.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my code, according to your question updates.

Comment: Please check that you are getting true value for scope.isIos

Comment: Instead of ng-if I used ng-show in <ion-nav-back-button> and it worked.

`<ion-nav-back-button ng-show="isIOS" class="button-icon icon-top_button_back light">`

Comment: Great! In order to help other people with the same issue, dont forget to mark this solution as an answer :)